# Start Instagram Options Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

My question is simple, Can i start Instagram's Options activity from another app (Where you can find friends, invite friends, change password, sign out...) via intent? Something like:

```
Intent insta_intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
    insta_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.instagram.android", "com.instagram.android.activity.UrlHandlerActivity"));
    insta_intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/settings"));
    startActivity(insta_intent);
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it would be something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.instagram",
         "com.instagram.SettingsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```